Exception caught by scheduler library
while using dropdown text field I got this error
LateInitializationError: Field '_listTileTextStyle@76295511' has not been initialized.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _DropDownTextFieldState._listTileTextStyle (package:dropdown_textfield/dropdown_textfield.dart)
#1      _DropDownTextFieldState.updateFunction.<anonymous closure> (package:dropdown_textfield/dropdown_textfield.dart:455:41)
dropdown_textfield.dart:455
#2      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1392:15)
binding.dart:1392
#3      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1326:11)
binding.dart:1326
#4      SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1035:9)
binding.dart:1035
#5      PlatformDispatcher.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:837:16)
platform_dispatcher.dart:837
#9      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
isolate_patch.dart:184
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)

Here's the code:
                         DropDownTextField(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                listTextStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                controller: gendercontroller,
                                clearOption: true,
                                dropdownColor: Colors.black,
                                textFieldDecoration:
                                    InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: gender,
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  fillColor: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value == null) {
                                    return "Required field";
                                  } else {
                                    print(gendercontroller
                                        .dropDownValue!.name);

                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                dropDownItemCount: 2,
                                dropDownList: const [
                                  DropDownValueModel(
                                      name: 'Male', value: "Male"),
                                  DropDownValueModel(
                                    name: 'Female',
                                    value: "Female",
                                  ),
                                ],
                                onChanged: (val) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    print(val);
                                  });
                                },
                              )

How to solve the problem

  // Adding _listTileTextStyle initialization
  late TextStyle _listTileTextStyle;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
     super.didChangeDependencies();
     _listTileTextStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.grey); 
     // Initialize _listTileTextStyle here
 }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

The variable : _listTileTextStyle has not successfully get initialized.
Try to initialize it on initState() method or whatever to deal with late modifier
